# How can find Center of circle to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry, unityscript

I have circle, and I'm trying to find center and convert to Vector2.

[image]

For example:

```
circleLocation : new Rect( Screen.width/10, Screen.height/2.75, Screen.width/3,Screen.width/3);

centerofcirle:New Vector2(circleLocation.width/3,    circleLocation.height/3);
```

But this example's not correct, the circle is not turn center. What is this formula? How can find correct center of cirle and how to convert Vector2?

Comment: The center would be divided by 2, not 3.

Comment: no it's not about that,circleLocation get 4 parameters,and centerofcirle get just 2,which parameters can be assing as starting point of circle.if you will help to find starting point,i promise that,i will divided 2, not need your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading between the lines here, I wonder if issue has nothing to do with your code here, but with the rotation point of your steering wheel object, which isn't where you want it to be.

A common technique to change the rotation point of a game object is to make that object the child of another game object in the Unity Editor. Then set the position of the child object as you wish relative to the position of the parent object. Now, rotate the parent object. The child object will automatically rotate around the parent object's position, since it's transform (including position/rotation) is relative to it's parent's.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be defining your circle using a Rect so just use the [Rect.center](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect-center.html) property:

```
circleLocation.center;
```

Comment: i think isnot helpfull for my situation,i just want to do steering wheel and should turn center of circle,and but now circle doesnot turn center. turn different point.i added screen shot for game.

Comment: Do you mean you need to perform a rotation around the centre of the circle? Why not just have a GameObject tho parent the circle, located at the circles origin, then rotate the GameObject around the Z axis?

Your picture shows a box with a circle in a corner. Rotating around the centre of the box in this case will of course cause the centre of the circle to move.